# (R) Error: unused arguments (forbidden = expression(x2 > x1))

Tags: r, function, optimization, bayesian

I am working with the R programming language. I am learning how to use the "mlrMBO" library for the purpose of optimizing multi-objective functions (using Bayesian Methods).

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlrMBO/index.html
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlrMBO/mlrMBO.pdf
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlrMBO/vignettes/mlrMBO.html
- https://github.com/mlr-org/mlrMBO

In my example, for the following constraints:

```
 x2 >x1 AND x4 >x3
```

I want to optimize the following (multi-objective) function I defined:

```
bayesian_function <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4) {
    var_1 <- sin(x1 + x2)
    var_2 <- cos(x1 - x2)
    var_3 <- x1 + x4
    var_4 <- x3 + x4 -7
        goal_1 = sum(var_1 + var_2 + var_3 + var_4)
    goal_2 = var_1 + var_2 - var_3 + var_4
    goal_3 = var_1 + var_2 - var_3 + 2*var_4

    return(c(goal_1, goal_2, goal_3))

}
```

To do this, I tried the follow the necessary "mlrMBO" syntax to optimize this function for the given constraints and allowed ranges for "x1, x2, x3, x4" :

```
#load libraries
library(mlrMBO)
library(ParamHelpers)
library(smoof)

obj.fn = makeMultiObjectiveFunction(
  name = "My test function",
  fn = function(x1, x2, x3, x4) {
    var_1 <- sin(x1 + x2)
    var_2 <- cos(x1 - x2)
    var_3 <- x1 + x4
    var_4 <- x3 + x4 -7
        goal_1 = sum(var_1 + var_2 + var_3 + var_4)
    goal_2 = var_1 + var_2 - var_3 + var_4
    goal_3 = var_1 + var_2 - var_3 + 2*var_4

    return(c(goal_1, goal_2, goal_3))

},
#define acceptable ranges
par.set = makeNumericParamSet(
     makeNumericParam("x1", lower = 20, upper = 40),
     makeNumericParam("x2", lower = 30, upper = 45),
     makeNumericParam("x3", lower = 10, upper = 20),
     makeNumericParam("x4", lower = 10, upper = 50),
#define constraints
     forbidden = expression(x2 >x1),
     forbidden = expression(x4 >x3)
),

minimize=TRUE
)

#create control gird
 control=makeMBOControl(propose.points=1, final.method="best.predicted", final.evals=10)
 control=setMBOControlTermination(control, iters=10)
 control=setMBOControlInfill(control, crit=makeMBOInfillCritEI())

#perform optimization
lrn=makeMBOLearner(control, obj.fun)
```

The first part of this code returns the following error and preventing me from running the rest of the code:

```
Error in makeNumericParamSet(makeNumericParam("x1", lower = 20, upper = 40),  : 
  unused arguments (forbidden = expression(x2 > x1), forbidden = expression(x4 > x3))
```

It seems that there is a problem while defining the constraints (i.e. "forbidden" statement). I tried reading more about this function https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ParamHelpers/versions/1.14/topics/makeParamSet , but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Can someone please show me why this error is being produced?

Thanks

UPDATE:

as per the answer provided by @blorp6, I tried to combine both "forbidden" statements into a single line of code:

```
obj.fn = makeMultiObjectiveFunction(
    name = "My test function",
    fn = function(x1, x2, x3, x4) {
        var_1 <- sin(x1 + x2)
        var_2 <- cos(x1 - x2)
        var_3 <- x1 + x4
        var_4 <- x3 + x4 -7
        goal_1 = sum(var_1 + var_2 + var_3 + var_4)
        goal_2 = var_1 + var_2 - var_3 + var_4
        goal_3 = var_1 + var_2 - var_3 + 2*var_4
        
        return(c(goal_1, goal_2, goal_3))
        
    },
    #define acceptable ranges
    par.set = makeParamSet(
        makeNumericParam("x1", lower = 20, upper = 40),
        makeNumericParam("x2", lower = 30, upper = 45),
        makeNumericParam("x3", lower = 10, upper = 20),
        makeNumericParam("x4", lower = 10, upper = 50),
        #define constraints
        forbidden = expression(x2 >x1 & x4 >x3)
    ),
    
    minimize=TRUE
)

#create control gird
     control=makeMBOControl(propose.points=1, final.method="best.predicted", final.evals=10)
     control=setMBOControlTermination(control, iters=10)
     control=setMBOControlInfill(control, crit=makeMBOInfillCritEI())
    
    #perform optimization
    lrn=makeMBOLearner(control, obj.fun)
```

But this produces a new error: `Error in fn(unlist(x), ...) : unused argument (unlist(x))`

Did I understand this correctly?
Thanks

Comment: `forbidden=` is a parameter to `makeParamSet`, not `makeNumericParamSet` which you are using. Also, parameter names but be unique in R. You cannot pass two parameters named `forbidden=`. You would need to combine those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're passing two arguments of the same name to `makeNumericParamSet()`, which only takes 1 argument of the name 'forbidden'. I checked `?makeNumericParamSet` in the R console, and saw that the function which takes 'par.set' and 'forbidden' as arguments is actually `makeParamSet`, so I tried this:

###### attempt

```
#define acceptable ranges
  par.set = makeParamSet(
    makeNumericParam("x1", lower = 20, upper = 40),
    makeNumericParam("x2", lower = 30, upper = 45),
    makeNumericParam("x3", lower = 10, upper = 20),
    makeNumericParam("x4", lower = 10, upper = 50),
    #define constraints
    forbidden = expression(x2 > x1 & x4 > x3)
    #forbidden = expression(x4 >x3)
  )
```

###### result

```
> par.set
      Type len Def   Constr Req Tunable Trafo
x1 numeric   -   - 20 to 40   -    TRUE     -
x2 numeric   -   - 30 to 45   -    TRUE     -
x3 numeric   -   - 10 to 20   -    TRUE     -
x4 numeric   -   - 10 to 50   -    TRUE     -
Forbidden region specified.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I tried to put everything together, but I got a new error. It was too long to post in the comments section. can you please take a look at the edit in the original question? thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I tried poking around some of the functions, but didn't really get anywhere. The issue seems to be with the function `makeMultiObjectiveFunction()`, and stepping through its source code only gave me more errors. I'm not familiar with the `mlrMBO` package, so I won't be of much help on this one, I'm afraid :/

Comment: thank you for all your help! I opened an issue on github - hopefully we will hear back from the maintainers of this package! thanks again!